# Como tornar o desenho de objetos de controle mais rápido em um formulário C#

Tags: c#, winforms, formulário, aplicação-desktop

Em um formulário, em C# para desktop, ocorre constantes movimentações de determinados controles. 
No caso estou usando objetos do tipo PictureBox, porém sua renderização é muito demorada.
É recomendado o uso de outro objeto de controle para isso? E tem como tornar a movimentação de determinado controle feita de maneira assíncrona?

Comment: Veja o código gerado pelo Visual Studio quando você desenha um formulário. Ele congela a renderização antes de adicionar os componentes e depois descongela - só aí os controles são rapidamente renderizados e fica imperceptível ao usuário. Eu não tenho Visual Studio aqui senão daria uma olhada e te diria qual é o comando. Mas você vai achar fácil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode colocar a lógica que quiser de forma assíncrona em um objeto da classe `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. Mas a atualização da tela é feita em um método interno que é síncrono. Se você quiser animar movimento de controles em uma aplicação de formulário, você está condenado a ter que lidar com flicker e com sua thread travada enquanto todos os controles são redesenhados. Não tem escapatória.

Se você realmente precisa dessas animações, você tem três opções:

- **Desenvolver como se fazia na época de Abraão**: faça o formulário com C++ puro, sem .NET, implementando seu próprio processo de desenho na tela (provavelmente inviável, certo?);
- **Para se manter no mundo .NET, você também pode utilizar XNA.** Mas XNA é mais apropriado para jogos. Me parece ser o que você está fazendo (nunca vi aplicativo de produtividade, tipo planilha ou processador de texto, com controles animados);
- **Utilizar o [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx).** É um "subframework" do .NET que foi criado, dentre outras coisas, para necessidades como a sua. Fica a dica  ;)

Comment: Mas eu preciso fazer o mesmo em um formulário desktop em c#

Comment: Então você vai ter que aprender a conviver com os problemas que você descreveu. Ossos do ofício.